# ConcurrentModificationException in merge sort code

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I'm a beginner to Java and coding in general. I'm trying to write a merge sort code for an ArrayList of a class I made called Member, but the code runs into a ConcurrentModificationException. isLargerThan is a custom method that I made to compare Members. What am I doing wrong?

```
  public static void mergeSort(List<Member> list) {
    List<Member> another1 = new ArrayList<Member>();
    another1 = list.subList(0, list.size() / 2);
    List<Member> another2 = new ArrayList<Member>();
    another2 = list.subList(list.size() / 2, list.size());
    if (another1.size() > 1) {
      mergeSort(another1);
    } if (another2.size() > 1) {
      mergeSort(another2);
    }
    merge(list, another1, another2);
  }

  public static void merge(List<Member> goal, List<Member> list1, List<Member> list2) {
    if (isLargerThan(list2.get(0), list1.get(0))) {
      goal = list1;
      goal.addAll(list2);
    } else {
      goal = list2;
      goal.addAll(list1);
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I have since changed the merge method to this:

```
  public static void merge(List<Member> goal, List<Member> list1, List<Member> list2) {
    if (isLargerThan(list2.get(0), list1.get(0))) {
      goal.clear();
      goal.addAll(list1);
      goal.addAll(list2);
    } else {
      goal.clear();
      goal.addAll(list2);
      goal.addAll(list1);
    }
  }
```

The error now appears on the first `goal.addAll(list1);` line, where before it appeared on the line `} if (another2.size() > 1) {`.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: The line that checks if (another2.size() > 1).

Answer (score 0):

The sublist is not an actual list, instead, it just store the reference of current list into it with start and end value.

Due to this, the `goal`, `list1`, `list2` of `merge` functional internally refers to same list.

As you are performing `goal.addAll(list2);` and `goal.addAll(list1);`, you are trying to perform read and write operation on same list causing `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To fix this issue, you can copy one list into another manually instead of using sublist.
Or create a separate list to merge the result.